# Custom field (ACF) image is not exclusive to the single post it's uploaded to and displays on every post type I create

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom post type with custom fields(ACF) for patient galleries. To upload the images, I created a custom field type of "Gallery". Problem is, when I upload an image on one post, these images end up showing across every instance of the post type. I can create 20 different post types and they all have the same images, they are not exclusive to the post type I uploaded them to.

```
<div class="swiper-container gallery-top gallery-top-home">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">

  <?php while ( $ba_loop->have_posts() ) : $ba_loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php
$images = get_sub_field('ba_photo');
?>

<?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
  </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div><!-- swiper wrapper end-->
  </div><!-- swiper container end-->
```

Comment: Use different template for each post type or add condition - ```if ($post->post_type == 'my-post-type') then show gallery```.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to get the id of the particular post..

Use this code..
$images = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ba_photo', true);

instead of this 
$images = get_sub_field('ba_photo');

The first code will differentiate every post by id, and you will get your required post details.